# CXF - catching/handling HTTP exceptions

Tags: cxf, httpurlconnection, sharepoint-api

This is rather a basic cxf usage question. How/where can we catch the actual HTTP exception/error. I kind of followed the Interceptor/MessageObserver concept but could not capture the HTTP error using them.

I see this error in the log4j log file.

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response
'401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://10.107.172.79/test/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
                at  org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
                at org.apache.cxf.transpot.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1448)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:614)
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
                ... 9 more
```

Only javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException with "Could not send Message."
message is thrown while calling the service

```
try{

      GetListCollectionResult result = port.getListCollection();

   }catch (javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException excep){

}
```

This is how we call the service.

To provide NTLM credentials:

```
Authenticator.setDefault( extended class of Authenticator);
```

Create the service.

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(ListsSoap.class);
factory.setAddress(list_url);
ListsSoap port = (ListsSoap) factory.create();
```

Update the conduit.

..

```
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
        httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Call service and get the result.

```
GetListCollectionResult result  = port.getListCollection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer in the CXF mailing list.

```
excep.getCause()
```

gives access to the underlying exception, in my case it is the HTTP Transport exception.